# Removing certain file types that do not contain the hostname in the file name

Tags: bash, files, uninstall, hostname, xargs

I am doing a file deployment for multiple machines per site, so it is much easier for me to zip all the files once and deploy to every machine. However I would like to remove the config for all the other PC's.

The zip contains various generic files, and also a specific config for each machine.

For example a less of the zip would provide:

```
generic1.xjson
generic2.xjson
generic3.xjson
generic1.yjson
generic2.yjson
PC-1-1.json
PC-1-2.json
PC-1-3.json
```

So I am looking to remove every PC-1-*.json that does not contain the PC's hostname.

(the PC hostnames are always exactly PC-1-1, etc.)

I was trying to do something along the lines of:

```
ls -1 | grep -v *$hostname* | xargs -0 rm *PC-*-*.json
```

This would remove all the files including the one for the current hostname.

Looking for what I have wrong in this, or if there is a better way of doing this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command does not work as expected because of `rm *PC-*-*.json`! it would expands by shell and includes all `PC-x-x.json` files.

Actually you're using `xargs` in a wrong way.

---

Something like this should do the job:

```
ls -Q1 | grep -v $hostname | grep -E "PC-1-[0-9]+\.json" | xargs echo
```

change `echo`  with `rm` when you where sure that it works.

A better solution would be using `find`:

```
find -type f -name "PC-*-*.json" -not -name "*$hostname*" -exec rm -i {} +
```

- remove `-i` from `rm` after you were sure that command is working correctly.

Comment: I ended up using the:

ls -Q1 | grep -v $HOSTNAME | grep -E "[0-99]+\.json" | xargs rm

Variant, I cut off the PC-1 part of the second grep, as there should never be any json in my environment that is formatted like this expect the files I want to target.

Also, like an idiot, I was using $hostname in place of $HOSTNAME, which, being relatively new to this I didn't know was not printing the hostname in my query.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Nice! I think it makes a difference if you switch the filename tests and do `-iname "PC-*-*.json" -not -iname "*$hostname*"` instead as the second one has to be evaluated much more seldom this way. Also, OP wants `-type f` (as the first test). Oh and wait, why `-iname`? OP definitely wants `name` for both tests.

Comment: @dessert You're right... I'll update the answer. `iname` is somehow burned into my memory and I always use it...

Comment: @AndrewWilliams You're welcome... about `HOSTNAME` you are correct! I thought `hostname` is a variable you defined youreslf ;)